# -[CLLocation length]: unrecognized selector after table display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash

Quite unexpectedly after doing some minor modifications, my code has started crashing with:

```
-[CLLocation length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b3739c0.
```

This happens after the app has completed the display of the cells of a table, more precisely after exiting:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I tried putting breakpoints in all length accesses in the code, but none of them was caught. I also set a breakpoint on [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] and this in fact was caught, but gave no information altogether. I also investigated the crash log but the last contact of the crashing thread with my app was in the main function. How may I discover the point of the program producing the crash?

Comment: Are you somehow assigning a `CLLocation` instance to one of the cell's labels in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: I do no think so, but this is a wonderful hint. In fact such an issue would be properly detected after all cells have been created when trying to display them. I will comment the population of the cell and see if that changes things.

Comment: Yes, in fact if I comment the population of the cell the crash goes out. Now I need to single out the offending instruction, but that would be a relatively minor issue. Thank you very much! I wonder if with Swift this kind of errors would be wiped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact one the table textfields was incorrectly a CLLocation. The only catch was the timing of the error. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`CLLocation` does not have a length method, see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/). If it's not your code (you seemed to imply that), maybe it's something in one of your dependencies?

Btw, you should add an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), it should catch that.

Comment: That I know, I had no intention to ask the length to a CLLLocation...
I put up and exception breakpoint but that was not caught. The only breakpoint to be caught is the one on doesNotRecognizeSelector